# Added NSMutableArray elements into another NSMutableArray in jumble way

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have `NSMutableArray` of 100 elements in it.

I want to load "20 - 50", "10 - 20", "60 - 100" and 50 - 60. elements into separate NSMutableArray and its Index value into another `NSMutableArray`.

is there away I can load `20 - 50` elements 30 count items after the `10 - 20` elements 10 count items then `60 - 100` items i.e 40 count finally `50 - 60` items 10 count items added into one new `NSmutableArray` and there index storied value into another `NSmutableArray`.

Is there a way i can add the items

```
NSMutableArray *valueArray; // Value array count is 100.

NSMutableArray *indexValue;
NSMutableArray *addValueRangeArray;
for (int i = 0; i< [ valueArray count  ]; i ++) {

if (i == 20 && i <= 50 )
{
 [addValueRangeArray addObject:[valueArray objectAtIndex:i]]; 
      [indexValue addObject:i];
}
}
```

Here its not working since for count loop starts 0 to 99
and items added starts from 0

I want to added item with range base where i do get objects added and also the index value too.

Your input are highly appreciated
Let me know if not understand the question.
Since its tricky one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subarrayWithRange` to get specific range from array.

```
if (valueArray.count >= 100) {
     NSMutableArray *rangeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [rangeArray addObjectsFromArray:[valueArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(20, 30)]];
     //and so on.
}
```

**Note:** With `NSMakeRange` passed first parameter as range's starting point and second one is length so pass the number of objects for that range, so for first range 20-50 it is `NSMakeRange(20, 30)`. It may cause you crash if your  `valueArray` doesn't have objects with that range.

Comment: its crashing after passing another one

Comment: @kiran can you add what error you are getting? and also show what you are trying in another one.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]: range {54, 65} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 65]'

Comment: @kiran I have already told you second argument in `NSMakeRange` is length so if you want object from `54-65` then make like `NSMakeRange(54, 11)` Also in question you have told that you array count  is 100 and in error it is saying that Array count is 66

Comment: ! Opps its my fault, Sorry! but its working for me Thanks!

Comment: @kiran Welcome mate :)

Comment: @Nirva D:   I forgot one thing about indexValue from the root NSMutableArray.  is it possible to store index value using range?

Comment: @kiran I know how to do that in swift, but doesn't know in objective c but you can do one thing make multiple for loop, first start with 20-30 and so one, or you can also ask a new question here for that.

Comment: I want to avoid that multiple loops.  I will try to convert swift to objective-c if possbile.

Comment: @kiran In swift it is simply like `let indexArray = [Int](20...50)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Temp1",@"Temp2",@"Temp3",@"Temp4",@"Temp5",@"Temp6",@"Temp7",@"Temp8",@"Temp9",@"Temp10",@"Temp11",@"Temp12",@"Temp13",@"Temp14",@"Temp15",@"Temp16",@"Temp17",@"Temp18", nil];


// Here create an array of your ranges through which you want your data

NSArray *arrIndex = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(3,4)],[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,4)],[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(11,7)],[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(7,4)], nil];


NSMutableArray *arrTemp = [NSMutableArray new];
for  (int i=0;i<arrIndex.count;i++) {
        [arrTemp addObject:[arr subarrayWithRange:[arrIndex[i] rangeValue]]];
    }

for (NSArray *arr in arrTemp) {
    NSLog(@"Arra - %@",arr);
}
```

As per your question your range would be

```
NSArray *arrIndex = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(20,30)],[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(10,10)],[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(60,40)],[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(50,10)], nil];
```